# Omitting fields during serialization for specific Gson serializer

Tags: log4j, gson, logstash, slf4j, log4j2

I have a stateless REST API build on Spring Boot 1.4.2. I want to log all the API calls into elk. Requests and responses data (headers, parameters, payload) need to be logged as well. I don't want to log them 1:1 - I want to filter out sensitive data etc.

I made an aspect that is intercepting my `@RestController`'s methods invocation. I created custom annotation for method's parameter that should be logged (I use it on payloads annotated as well by `@RequestBody`) following [this](http://vlkan.com/blog/post/2015/01/30/java-null-check/) article and it gave me access to my data transfer objects in my `@Around` advice. I dont care about their type - I would like to call `logger.debug(logObject)` and send this log to logstash.

As far as I understand log message should be send as JSON with JSONLayout set in Log4j2 appender to ease things on the logstash side. So I serialize my `logObject` into JSON log message but during this and this only serialization I want to filter sensitive data out. I can not use `transient` because my controller depends on the same field.

Can I somehow create an `@IgnoreForLogging` annotation, that will be detected only by my custom Gson serializer that I use within logging advice and will be ignored within standard Spring's infrastructure? Is my logging into logstash approach even correct (I am trying to set it up for the first time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I missed that in documentation. [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-User-Defined-Exclusion-Strategies) is the link

My custom annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface IgnoreForLogging {
}
```

Strategy for serializing objects:

```
public class LoggingExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes fieldAttributes) {
        return fieldAttributes.getAnnotation(IgnoreForLogging.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Serializing log message in aspect class:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new LoggingExclusionStrategy())
            .create();
String json = gson.toJson(logObject);
```

This way Spring internally uses default serializer that doesn't know about `@IgnoreForLogging` and I can take advantage of my annotation in other places.